# Python - reading data from file with variable attributes and line lengths

Tags: python

I'm trying to find the best way to parse through a file in Python and create a list of namedtuples, with each tuple representing a single data entity and its attributes. The data looks something like this:

```
UI: T020  
STY: Acquired Abnormality  
ABR: acab   
STN: A1.2.2.2  
DEF: An abnormal structure, or one that is abnormal in size or location, found   
in or deriving from a previously normal structure.  Acquired abnormalities are  
distinguished from diseases even though they may result in pathological   
functioning (e.g., "hernias incarcerate").   
HL: {isa} Anatomical Abnormality

UI: T145   
RL: exhibits   
ABR: EX   
RIN: exhibited_by   
RTN: R3.3.2   
DEF: Shows or demonstrates.   
HL: {isa} performs   
STL: [Animal|Behavior]; [Group|Behavior]   

UI: etc...
```

While several attributes are shared (eg UI), some are not (eg STY). However, I could hardcode an exhaustive list of necessary.
Since each grouping is separated by an empty line, I used split so I can process each chunk of data individually:

```
input = file.read().split("\n\n")
for chunk in input:
     process(chunk)
```

I've seen some approaches use string find/splice, itertools.groupby, and even regexes. I was thinking of doing a regex of '[A-Z]*:' to find where the headers are, but I'm not sure how to approach pulling out multiple lines afterwards until another header is reached (such as the multilined data following DEF in the first example entity).

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Could we assume that the 'header' is always a two or three capital letters followed by semicolon?

Comment: Is each `KEY:`-`value` pair on a single line? It looks like `DEF:` may be on several lines.

Comment: @J0HN Yes, all headers are 2-3 capital letters followed by a colon.

Comment: @Robᵩ You are right, DEF: is on several lines. This is the problem I'm having.

Comment: by semicolon you guys mean [colon `:`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_%28punctuation%29)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took assumption that if you have string span on multiple lines you want newlines replaced with spaces (and to remove any additional spaces).

```python
def process_file(filename):
    reg = re.compile(r'([\w]{2,3}):\s') # Matches line header
    tmp = '' # Stored/cached data for mutliline string
    key = None # Current key
    data = {}

    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        for row in f:
            row = row.rstrip()
            match = reg.match(row)

            # Matches header or is end, put string to list:
            if (match or not row) and key:
                data[key] = tmp
                key = None
                tmp = ''

            # Empty row, next dataset
            if not row:
                # Prevent empty returns
                if data:
                    yield data
                    data = {}

                continue

            # We do have header
            if match:
                key = str(match.group(1))
                tmp = row[len(match.group(0)):]
                continue

            # No header, just append string -> here goes assumption that you want to
            # remove newlines, trailing spaces and replace them with one single space
            tmp += ' ' + row

    # Missed row?
    if key:
        data[key] = tmp

    # Missed group?
    if data:
        yield data
```

This generator returns `dict` with pairs like `UI: T020` in each iteration (and always at least one item).

Since it uses generator and continuous reading it should be effective event on large files and it **won't** read whole file into memory at once.

Here's little demo:

```python
for data in process_file('data.txt'):
    print('-'*20)
    for i in data:
        print('%s:'%(i), data[i])

    print()
```

And actual output:

```
--------------------
STN: A1.2.2.2
DEF: An abnormal structure, or one that is abnormal in size or location, found in or deriving from a previously normal structure.  Acquired abnormalities are distinguished from diseases even though they may result in pathological functioning (e.g., "hernias incarcerate").
STY: Acquired Abnormality
HL: {isa} Anatomical Abnormality
UI: T020
ABR: acab

--------------------
DEF: Shows or demonstrates.
STL: [Animal|Behavior]; [Group|Behavior]
RL: exhibits
HL: {isa} performs
RTN: R3.3.2
UI: T145
RIN: exhibited_by
ABR: EX
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I can only mark one answer as correct, but this solution certainly works.

Comment: @Aaron I don't see how accepted answer would work on large files (generator will always load just one part of file, not whole file at once) and how does he handle `\n\n`... But I guess it's good enough for you :)

Comment: I see what you mean, as his processes only one entity (group). But I ended up turning his solution into a function which gets called to process each data entity (grouping) and is then appended to a list. I really apologize, as yours is certainly exhaustive, I just chose the one I ended up using..

Comment: @Aaron I don't mind :) (really) I'm not angry or anything... :P I just hope you don't really call `input = file.read().split("\n\n")` because it causes unnecessary loading of **whole** file to memory at once instead of continuous reading.

Comment: Oh I see. In this case I've changed my answer for the sake of efficiency (as the data file is actually a bit large). Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Aaron thanks, feel free to add debug notices to `process_file` around `yield`, to see that it doesn't process file at once but rather waits after each `yield` until it gains control gain (next iteration trough `foreach`), thus it always uses as little memory as possible. (I honestly love this concept in python and I'm glad you got it too). I've also added note on how the file isn't loaded at once.

Answer (score 2):

```python
source = """
UI: T020  
STY: Acquired Abnormality  
ABR: acab   
STN: A1.2.2.2  
DEF: An abnormal structure, or one that is abnormal in size or location, found   
in or deriving from a previously normal structure.  Acquired abnormalities are  
distinguished from diseases even though they may result in pathological   
functioning (e.g., "hernias incarcerate").   
HL: {isa} Anatomical Abnormality
"""

inpt = source.split("\n")  #just emulating file

import re
reg = re.compile(r"^([A-Z]{2,3}):(.*)$")
output = dict()
current_key = None
current = ""
for line in inpt:
    line_match = reg.match(line) #check if we hit the CODE: Content line
    if line_match is not None:
        if current_key is not None:
            output[current_key] = current #if so - update the current_key with contents
        current_key = line_match.group(1)   
        current = line_match.group(2)
    else:
        current = current + line   #if it's not - it should be the continuation of previous key line

output[current_key] = current #don't forget the last guy
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

def process(chunk):
    split_chunk = re.split(r'^([A-Z]{2,3}):', chunk, flags=re.MULTILINE)
    d = dict()
    fields = list()
    for i in xrange(len(split_chunk)/2):
        fields.append(split_chunk[i])
        d[split_chunk[i]] = split_chunk[i+1]
    my_tuple = namedtuple(split_chunk[1], fields)
    return my_tuple(**d)
```

should do. I think I'd just do the `dict` though -- why are you so attached to a `namedtuple`?